# How to retrieve the json data sending via curl in Django Tastypie?

Tags: json, django, curl, tastypie

I'm sending a json data via curl command. How do I retrieve it back ?

Here is my `curl`  command

```
 curl -XPOST -i -g http://localhost:8000/api/v1/controllers/register/ -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"installation_id": 1, "name":"xyz"}'
```

Here is my view

```
def api_controllers_register(self,bundle,**kwargs):
        print "bundle",bundle.data
```

**prepend_url**

```
def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/lastevent%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('api_controllers_register'), name="api_controllers_register"),
               ]
```

It doesn't print my json data. Instead it throws an error saying

```
"'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'",
```

How do I retrieve my json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this command    print request.body